# How to get javadoc when using sbt and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, scala-ide, typesafe-activator

I use Activator/Sbt to create a new project, add the libraries I want to add in Sbt config file then I generate an Eclipse project from sbt.

My problem is that I don't see any documentation when I'm coding in Eclipse, is there a way to download and add all the javadocs when generating the Eclipse project from Sbt?

The way I generate the project from Sbt is by using

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/

and just running "eclipse" in sbt/activator console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
sbt "eclipse with-source=true"
```

It will download the javadocs and tell eclipse where to find them.

Alternatively, you can add [the following](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse#withsource) to your sbt config file:

```
EclipseKeys.withSource := true
```